# how to use css to achieve html that video's width=device's width on the mobile phone, video's width=600px on the computer

Tags: css

i am using css to change video's width that play in web page. I want to make video's width=device's width on the mobile phone, video's width=600px on the computer. But I failed.

html is:

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
  <video width='600'  poster='Monument_Valley2_Cover.jpg' controls>
     <source src='Monument_Valley2.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
</body>
```

I don't want to use "user-scalable=yes", and i don't want to make web page look small on the mobile phone.
When I specify the video width=600px, the video width always exceeds the device width on the mobile phone. I failed.
how do I use css to achieve this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries to set the width of the video. Check this link to see examples -> [css-media-queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
  video {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Please note that I have to use `!important` to overwrite the inline-style width you had set to the video. If you use CSS to set the width of 600px for other resolutions, important wouldn't be needed.